# How to make a top bar component responsive

Tags: css, next.js, responsive-design, responsive, next.js13

In my top navigation bar component, I have the following minimized structure:

```
export default function Topbar() {

  // states, hooks, etc.

  return (
    <div
      className={twMerge(
        "z-40 fixed top-0 left-0 w-full py-4 grid grid-cols-2",
        ifScrolled && "bg-black/70 backdrop-blur transition-all duration-1000"
      )}
    >
      <div className="flex justify-start items-center px-10">
        <Logo />
      </div>

      <div className="p-4 md:hidden flex justify-end items-center">
        <button
          className="p-2 rounded hover:bg-white/10 transition-all duration-300"
          onClick={() => {
            setDrawer(true);
          }}
        >
          <MenuIcon />
        </button>
      </div>

      {/* DRAWER */}

      {/* DESKTOP HORIZONTAL MENU ITEMS */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This works well on desktop. But in mobile, it overflows to the right-hand side. I added a hamburger menu but its icon appears outside of the screen.

[image]

However, when clicked to the icon, it appears on the actual mobile screen, not overflowing.
[image]

Any help would be really appreciated. My focus is to cutting of the overflowing part of the top navigation bar, because otherwise the screen is horizontally scrollable (i.e., to the right), which is not desired.